# Performance, website-performance, software-performance, performance-tools and job-performance tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Currently, there are five tags containing "performance" in their title:

- [performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) (141, 38) *“Questions related to improving application performance [...]”*,
- [software-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-performance) **(10, 4)** No wiki summary,
- [web-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-performance) **(9, 0)** No wiki summary,
- [performance-tools](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tools) **(4, 1)** No wiki summary,
- [job-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-performance) **(7)** *“Questions related to excelling at one's current job [...] performance review”*.

I think that:

1. [software-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-performance) and [web-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-performance) brings nothing useful compared to the more popular [performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance), and so they must be merged. [web-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-performance) might be more specific (for example, a question about CSS sprites is better tagged [web-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-performance) than [performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) since the technique is directly related to web, but still, the tag was not used very often to show its benefit. As for [software-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-performance), I believe [Does object-orientation really affect algorithm performance?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/125753/6605) question illustrates quite well how a more general [performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) would be more appropriate.
2. [performance-tools](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tools) may be removed too, since it probably encourages off-topic questions of two types: [the ones](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/105285/6605) where people will ask for product recommendations (off-topic), and the ones where people will ask how to use a specific product related to performance (off-topic, belongs to Super User).
3. [job-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-performance) is a very different kind. It's not related to [performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) as it is defined in its wiki summary, but to the job, specifically the job of a developer. Therefore, this tag must remain.

Comment: Related: [Request for comment: structured tag cleanups](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/request-for-comment-structured-tag-cleanups)